# GraphQL + Relay modern fragment gives me an array of null posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, relay

Im developing a React Native app using Relay modern, GraphQL, and Graphcool. I'm trying to fetch the posts from the DB, and I have 3 files, Post.js, PostList, and the index.js.

**PostList.js:**

```js
export default createFragmentContainer(PostList, graphql`
  fragment PostList_viewer on Viewer {
    allPosts(last: 100, orderBy: createdAt_ASC) @connection(key: "PostList_allPosts", filters: []) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...Post_post
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

**Post.js**

```js
export default createFragmentContainer(Post, graphql`
  fragment Post_post on Post {
    id
    content
    createdAt
    author {
      id
      username
    }
  }
`)
```

**index.js**

```js
const Feed = () => (
  <QueryRenderer
    environment={environment }
    query={AllPostQuery}
    render={({ error, props }) => {
      if (error) {
        return <div>{error.message}</div>
      } else if (props) {
        return <PostList viewer={props.viewer} />
      }
      return <Text>Loading</Text>
    }}
  />
)
```

When I console log `this.props.viewer.allPosts` inside **PostList.js** I get `{ edges: [ null, null, null ], ...`. I have 3 posts in the DB so it's finding the posts, but why are they null? Pl

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you run into problems try to log the "root" object which is `props` not a branch inside of it - this will make easier for you to undestrand data structure.

Also, as far as I know Relay does some magic which makes data available for you only in files where you defined a fragment, so in PostList.js you will not see details of the post. Try printing data from Post.js. That's possibly the reason why you see `null` values printed.

Also data from GraphQL be will be available for you under variable name derived from fragment name after `_` (underscore), so in your example it will be `post` not `allPosts`.

Comment: I know all that, none of that was my problem, . Also, `allPosts` is not wrong, it's part of the object I get from Graphcool, the object I got was `viewer: { allPosts: {edges: node{...} }}`. Nothing worked for me, not even using `post`. My problem ended up being authentication.